# I am trying to make a python script that add iptables to my server and I am getting some errors

Tags: python, linux, networking, iptables

I Am trying to make a python script that adds iptables to a linux server most of the tables work

if do somthing like

```py
def run(cmd):
 subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
run("iptables -A INPUT   -m recent --name portscan --rcheck --seconds 86400 -j DROP")
```

It works but when I do something like

```py
run("iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m string --algo bm --hex-string "|535444|" -j DROP")
```

I get errors.

It would be nice if I could get some help with this?

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. A description alone is not enough. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Did you mean to use run("iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m string --algo bm --hex-string " + str(535444) + " -j DROP") ?